# Why this ideal is a subset of $K[x_0, \dots, x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals

For a point in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$, $p = [a_0:a_1:\dots :a_n]$, how to see that $$I(p) = \left <  x_ia_j - x_ja_i: 0 \leq i \leq n, 0 \leq i \leq n \right> \subseteq K[x_0, \dots,x_n].$$

How does having points from the projective space make this any diffferent from a regular problem? Isn't having the generators from the $K[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ enough?

Comment: I guess by ideal it means a homogenous ideal of the graded ring

Comment: @Wilf-Fine, yes that is true. But why does that make it special?

Comment: Yes, the question as you pose it is trivial. $I(p)$ is an ideal of $K[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ by definition.  Check back in the context where you found the question and try to find what the problem is about.  Have you checked that it is proper?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#First_properties Check here if you are asking what homogeneous ideal stands for. I can't be sure what you are asking specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that the coefficients $a_i$ are defined only up to scalar, so you have to check that the definition makes sense. But this is okay since if you consider an equivalent tuple (i.e. obtained by multiplying all the $a_i$ by a non-zero scalar $ \lambda \in K$) then the new generators for $I(p)$ are just multiples of the old ones by $\lambda$, which is invertible in $K$. Then they define a same ideal.